# Not able to find a class in package

Tags: java, package

Consider a package hierarchy `folder1/hi`. `folder1` contains A.java and `hi` contains B.java.

B.java:

```
package aa.pkg;
public class B { }
```

A.java:

```
package hi.aa.pkg;
public class A {B b; }
```

Now B.java compiles successfully, but A.java does not.

I am using these commands in cmd (if the current directory is `folder1`):

```
javac -d hi hi/B.java
javac -cp hi -d . A.java
```

It says class B not found.

What is the correct cmd commands to compile A.java or what should the code look like for this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import class B into Class A. because both classes are in different packages.

```
package hi.aa.pkg;
import aa.pkg.B;
public class A {B b; }
```

Comment: Thanks that works But if Both A and B are in same package But package statements in both are different then still we require to import B.class

Comment: If both classes are in the same package then you don't need `import ` statement.