# Relationship between a package statement and the directory of a .java file?

Tags: java, package

Consider a package hierarchy folder1/hi. folder1 contains B.java and hi contains A.java.

B.java:

```
package hi.a12.pkg;
public class B { }
```

A.java:

```
package a12.pkg;
public class A {B b; }
```

Now B.java compiles successfully, but A.java does not.

Since both should produce class files in same location. Hence they should be able to find each other without import statement.

But still It says class B not found.

Anyone suggest the measures...or whats going wrong..

Comment: How exactly are you compiling them, and from where? (I strongly suspect you're just compiling them from the wrong place...)

Comment: It doesn't seem like your package names are matching up with your folder hierarchy. `hi.a12.pkg.B` should be in `[some prefix]/hi/a12/pkg/B.java`. I don't get why you don't use the same package prefix for A.

Comment: After compiling B.java, I m compiling A.java from hi folder using cmd command : javac -cp . -d . A.java

Comment: @JonSkeet *I strongly suspect you're just compiling them from the wrong place*. That's a pretty incorrect statement to be making. No matter where you try compiling the classes from, the fact that they are in a directory structure different from the `package` statement will *always* prevent one of them from being compiled.

Comment: @ChetanKinger: I had missed the fact that they were in different packages not matching the folder structure... (Having said that, the *statement* was correct, in that I *did* strongly suspect that... it's just the suspicion that was incorrect :)

Comment: @JonSkeet Agreed. The *strong suspicion* that you had was incorrect in this case ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Consider a package hierarchy folder1/hi. folder1 contains B.java and
>   hi contains A.java.

So `B.java` is in `folder1` and `A.java` is in a folder named `hi`. So far so good.

`B.java` looks like this :

```
package hi.a12.pkg;
public class B { }
```

Oops. `B.java` says that it is in a `package` named `hi.a12.pkg` and yet it's physical location on the disk is `folder1`. That's where the problem is. Put your files in the folder indicated by the `package` statement or else other classes will not be able to find them.

A quick way to understand the concept and fix your problem would be to :

1. Change the `package` statement in `B.java` to `package folder1;`.
2. Change the `package` statement in `A.java` to `package folder1.hi;`
3. `import` `B` in `A.java` after the `package` statement as `import folder.B;`
4. Compile `B.java` from one directory above `folder1` as `javac folder1\B.java`
5. Compile `A.java` from one directory above `folder1` as `javac folder1\hi\A.java`

You can read all about it in the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/managingfiles.html)

Comment: I think package name is only used to specify location where class file should be created.so here B.class file is created in hi>a12>pkg>B.class So here should not be any problem

Comment: @Ronaldo7 That's an incorrect understanding. A `package` name is a part of the fully qualified name of a class. When you compile a `class` that has a `package` name, the fully qualified name of the `class` is `packagename.classname`. That's the reason `Java` has import statements. So that you don't have to write `packaganame.classname` everywhere in your code and you can just use a shorthand after you `import` the class. Please try out my suggestions.

Comment: My initial code was making hi.a12.pkg.B qualified name for B class Ok! In A.java i am using this qualified name as a12.pkg.A both are creating class files in same package still they are not accessible to each other [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30982793/not-able-to-find-a-class-in-package) see comment..

Comment: step 5 u have given still not compiling: giving bad class file, class file contains wrong class folder1.hi.B

Answer (score -1):

There are several problems.

First, it looks like your packages are named the wrong way around.  Try

for A.java (which should be in the directory ..../pkg/a12):

```
package pkg.a12;
```

for B.java (which must be in the directory .../pkg/a12/hi):

```
package pkg.a12.hi;
```

Second, your file A.java needs to say where B is located using an import statement:

```
package pkg.a12;
import pkg.a12.hi.B;
public class A {B b; }
```

Third, when you compile A you must be in the folder above pkg and refer to the full path of A:

```
javac pkg/a12/A.java
```

This will also compile B.java

Comment: In case you overlooked this part of the question, here it is : *folder1 contains B.java and hi contains A.java.*. Now when you say *First, it looks like your packages are named the wrong way around*, I am sure you realize that it's irrelevant how the packages are named.

Comment: Good point - thanks, Chetan.  I did what I often do and read the code but not the "comments", assuming that the true intention was in the code.  But it may not be and your answer is better in dealing with that discrepancy.  I tried to cover the broader scenario including the lack of import and the possibility that the compilation was being done incorrectly.

Comment: Good point about the import. I had overlooked it. However, the primary problem was the OP's understanding of the relationship between a `package` and a physical location on the computer which is apparent from the first few lines of the question.